# $\phi(a)=a$ and $\phi(x)=\alpha$ (utterance doubt)

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $L$ extension of field $K$ and $\alpha \in L$.

$\phi : K[x]\rightarrow L $ for
$\phi(a)=a$ ,$\forall a \in K\tag{1}$

and

$\phi(x)=\alpha\tag{2}.$

(Sorry, for english I used google translator.)

My doubt is these two pieces of information are not conflicting? (1) and (2).

Because from what I understand by (1) this function would occur for example $\phi(1)=1 , \phi(2)=2$ [ obviously since $1 , 2 \in K$] .
However, from what I understood from $\phi(x)$ would we have a constant function in $\alpha$ ? How do these two pieces of information interact?

---

(Obs:Below are the questions related to the statement, BUT their purpose here is not to ask for advice or the resolution itself, they are here only to help clarify the statement.)

a)Prove $\phi$ is Ring Homomorphism.

b)$\alpha$ is transcendent for $K$ if, and only if , $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Do you mean $\exists x$ with $x \neq \alpha$ and $\phi(x) = \alpha$?

Comment: @TomKern the question is written exactly like that in the book

Answer (score 0):

This should either be a $K$-automorphism of $L,$ i.e. $\phi\, : \,L\longrightarrow L$ which fixes all elements of $K,$ i.e. $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in K,$ or we could consider a ring homomorphism $\phi\, : \,K[x]\longrightarrow L$ with $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in K$ and $\phi(x)=\alpha \in L.$ Both is possible and make sense in the context. A mixture of both yields to the confusion you mentioned. Let's make an example: $K=\mathbb{R},L=\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}(i)\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1).$ In that case we could e.g. choose $\phi(x+iy)=x-iy$ as a field automorphism of $L=\mathbb{C}$ that fixes all elements from $K=\mathbb{R}$. The other possibility is the ring homomorphism $\phi\, : \,\mathbb{R}[x]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as $\phi(p(x))=p(i)$ for all real polynomials $p$.

I assume the latter is meant because this is a ring homomorphism and also solves problem b). This means someone made a typo and it has to be $\phi\, : \,K[x]\longrightarrow L.$

Comment: I made a mistake forgetting to put K[x] in the function. @Marius S.L.